# Reloading pages with AngularJS served by Apache

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I have an Angular app which uses some redirections. Here a snippet from my app.js:

```
'use strict';

var cacheBustSuffix = Date.now();

angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.filters', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'routeStyles'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider
                        .html5Mode({enabled: true,
                            requireBase: false})
                        .hashPrefix('!');

                $routeProvider
                        .when('/', {
                            redirectTo: '/myApp'
                        }).
                        when('/myApp', {
                            templateUrl: '/partials/home.html?cache-bust=' + cacheBustSuffix,
                            controller: 'ctrlHome'
                        }).
                        when('/myApp/search', {
                            templateUrl: '/partials/search.html?cache-bust=' + cacheBustSuffix,
                            controller: 'ctrlSearch'
                        }).
                        otherwise({
                            templateUrl: '/partials/404.html?cache-bust=' + cacheBustSuffix,
                            controller: 'ctrl404'});
            }]);
```

The whole thing is served by Apache 2.4. Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

I can manually and automatically reload pages but when I do that looks like the browser re-read only the partial that has to be refreshed, not the index + partial that I'd like to show. As a consequence all the styles and scripts fail to load, and I loose the both the interface and functionality. I think this might be a problem with the .htaccess file but as a beginner with Apache I'm not really confident with it. Anyone knows how to tell the server to re-read both the index.html and the view on refreshes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing to set

```
    <base href="your/app/path">
```

in your index.html
If you set this tag you will be good to go, also using $locationProvider turn on your html5 mode like this $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
Your .htaccess works fine.